# least residue of 100! + 102! mod 101

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Here is what I have:

want least $x$ s.t. $x \equiv_{101} 100! + 102!$

by Wilsons theorem

$100! \equiv_{101} -1$ **

and we know

$102 \equiv_{101} 1$

I was thinking:

$x \equiv_{101} 100!(1 + 101 \cdot 102)$

then $102$ becomes $1$? and again $102$ becomes $1$ hence

$x \equiv_{101} 100!$ and from ** we get $x = -1$

I KNOW THE LEAST RESIDUE IS 1, how do I go from the residue I got which is -1 to the LEAST residue?

Comment: Hint: $102!\bmod101=0$.

Comment: I don't know what you're saying, $102!\equiv 0\mod{101}$

Comment: then my approach is already taking this into consideration, because from my first statement if you use $102! \equiv_{101} 0$ you obtain my last line

Comment: Depends on what "smallest residue," but most times, I'd take "smallest" to imply "smallest non-negative," in which case $-1$ would be the answer...

Comment: LOL brother thanks!!! that's where I'm stuck, I need least so smallest nonnegative. but -1 is not a nonnegative number lol

Comment: Note that $-1\equiv100\pmod{101}$

Comment: that follows from me saying $102_{101} 1$ lol

Comment: @ThomasAndrews how do I go from my -1 answer to the 1 answer which is the least positive residue

Comment: No, $-1$ has a positive residue, too, and it is not $1.$

Comment: is it 100? modulo 101

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$100!+102!\equiv -1+0\equiv -1\equiv 100\bmod 101$